# not able to sync from server to server to /etc/letsencrypt location

Tags: server, permissions, cron, rsync, etc

I am making a cron job on my server node that uses haproxy base concated cert file from letsencrypt.
however when I am at home I have same dns pointing to the home server which is actually hosting the website so the domain I access is directly via local server IP me being on same shared network.
and since the certbot runs on proxy node server on digitalocean, I need to rsync the uncocatenated cert files folders /etc/letsencrypt/live and /etc/letsencrypt/archive to my home server

the cron task runs as root user:
but when trying to rsync it gives me permission error:

```
# rsync -e "sudo ssh -p 5322" -arvzh /etc/letsencrypt/live chaozhang@10.8.0.8:/etc/letsencrypt
sending incremental file list
rsync: failed to set times on "/etc/letsencrypt/live": Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/etc/letsencrypt/live/README": Permission denied (13)
live/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
live/xyz.com/
sent 433 bytes received 370 bytes 146.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1.58K speedup is 1.97
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1330) [sender=3.2.3]
```

and since i am running as root and root user on destination server does have privilages to write on the /etc/letsencrypt folder still i get error:

```
#/etc/letsencrypt# ll
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Aug 10 19:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 119 root root 12288 Aug 9 22:24 ../
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Aug 10 19:48 archive/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 1 22:26 csr/
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Aug 1 22:26 keys/
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Aug 10 19:48 live/
```

how can I fix this permission issue to rsync. keeping the desination permission unaltered and match the source